# Empty values retrieved with values_list

Tags: python, django

I have this list of countries retrieved from database based on one column (`country_name`) of the `country` table:

```
list_countries = Country.objects.values_list('country_name', flat=True).distinct()
```

result is like this:

```
[u'', u'China', u'France', u'Germany', ...]
```

Some of values in database are empty. How do I remove the empty retrieved so that I get the result retrieved just with country_name not null (cf `country_name != ''` ) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) object,

```
from django.db.models import Q
list_countries = Country.objects.filter(~Q(country_name='')).values_list('country_name', flat=True).distinct()
```

Comment: This is more idiomatic for Django than my answer, and will be faster for large sets as the filtering happens in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension to remove the zero length entries.

```
list_countries = [country for country in list_countries if len(country) > 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have agree with Adem's answer except for one change.

```
from django.db.models import Q
list_countries = Country.objects.filter(~Q(country_name='')).distinct().values_list('country_name', flat=True)
```

This will be slightly better than Adem's answer.